# Django BooleanField value

Tags: django

I have a form field like so

```
IS_EMPLOYED_CHOICES = (
    ('1', 'yes'), ('0', 'no')
    )
class AddEmployee(forms.Form):
    is_employed = forms.ChoiceField(choices=IS_EMPLOYED_CHOICES)
```

and the field in the model is a `BooleanField`

```
is_employed = models.BooleanField()
```

I am aware that a `BooleanField` is a varchar with either a `'1'` or `'0'` for `True` or `False`

However I want to pass this value from the model to the form field above so it would show `no` when it is False and `yes` when it is true.

```
 emp_profile = Employees.objects.get(pk=1)
 emp_form = AddEmployee(initial={
      'is_employed' = emp_profile.is_employed
 })
```

does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the value actually comes out, it's `True` and `False` instead of `'1'` and `'0'`.

So you would do something like

```
IS_EMPLOYED_CHOICES = (
    (True, 'yes'), (False, 'no')
    )
```

and it should work

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work if you remove the quotes :
IS_EMPLOYED_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'yes'), (0, 'no')
    )
(nod) Good luck